# Generics with Collection

Tags: java, generics, collections

Question 1:
Given:

```
  List<Object> lo = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

if I understand correctly, the parameter in `ArrayList<>()` must be `Object`, so do we need to write it? Or we just skip it like this:

```
List<Object> lo = new ArrayList<>();
```

Question 2:
Given:

```
List<? extends Animal> myArray = new ArrayList<Dog>();
```

as I understand, the left side of `=` means `myArray` is a reference of `List` type, which can be `List<Cat>` or `List<Dog>`, .... What about the right side of `=`, what does it mean? Does it mean that the reference `myArray` is assigned to an real object of `List` which contains only `Dog`? If yes, I can't not think about a situation when the information in the right side of `=` is useful or necessary. Can you give me an example where

```
     ... = new ArrayList<Dog>();
```

is essential or at least useful?

Comment: What do you mean - "*What about the right side of =, what does it mean? Does it mean that the reference myArray is assigned to an real object of List which contains only Dog? If yes, I can't not think about a situation when the information in the right side of = is useful or necessary.*"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question:  [Java 7 introduces the diamond operator](http://radar.oreilly.com/2011/09/java7-features.html), which acts as syntactic sugar for writing out the full types of generics in most cases.  It can be omitted, but it's "still there".

Second question:

- The left side is a list that is an [upper-bounded generic wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html).  It *contains* any object that either extends or implements a class named `Animal`.  You won't be able to insert any values into that list unless the list is defined instead as a [lower-bounded generic wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html) (using the `super` keyword).  There's a fair bit more on how to use them, when to use them, and how to categorize them  [in this Java Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html).
- The right side is a bit unusual to be dangling there, but it can be used to assign to an upper-bound generic type list, *if you populate the list you want first*.

  ```
  List<? extends Animal> fooList = new ArrayList<>();
  List<Dog> barList = new ArrayList<>();
  barList.add(new Dog());
  barList.add(new Dog());
  barList.add(new Dog());
  barList.add(new Dog());

  fooList = barList;
  ```

  You would still have to iterate over it as the upper-bound generic type:

  ```
  for(Animal d : fooList) {
      d.walk();
      d.talk();
  }
  ```

Essentially, the way you have it now is both misleading and not helpful, since that new `ArrayList<Dog>` is empty, and can't be added to.

Answer (score 2):

**Q1:** You can skip it in Java 7.

**Q2:** This declaration does not have much sense. `List<? extends SomeClass>` is useful as an argument of the method, in order to allow the developer to pass all kinds of Lists that contain something that extends SomeClass. However, it forbids to add anything into that list:

```
public void addAnimal(List<? extends Animal> animals) {
      animals.add(new Dog()); // Compiler error
}
```

if you want to achieve that, you will have to use super keyword: `List<? super SomeClass>`.

See also:

- [Lesson: Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can do that, as long as you are using Java 7, so long as the reference type does not contain a wildcard (as in `List<? extends Number>`).
2. When you use a wildcard, you are allowed to perform only the typesafe operations. In this case, you can read out of the list.

For example:

```
List<? extends Number> list = ...;
//more code
Number n = list.get(0);
```

But you **cannot** put elements into the list:

```
List<? extends Number> list = ...;
//more code
list.add(new Double(1.5));  //compile-time error
```

You can't, because you don't know the actual type of `list`. What if the type is not `Double` and is instead `Integer`?

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean that the reference myArray is assigned to an real object of List which contains only Dog?

it means that myArray is assigned to a list containing Dog or any kind of dog which derives from Dog, but in use of myArray, you are only guaranteed that the objects containing in myArray is Animals. note that in java, the type parameter is erased on compile.